# Redux dispatch action

Tags: redux

I am just trying to run a simple redux program when i use command node index it shows me error that action must be plain objects below is my code for that

```
const redux = require('redux')
const createStore = redux.createStore
const BUY_CAKE = 'BUY_CAKE'
function buyCake () {
  return
  {
    type: BUY_CAKE
  }
}

const initialState = {
  numOfCakes: 10
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BUY_CAKE: return {
      ...state,
      numOfCakes: state.numOfCakes - 1
    }
    default: return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer)
console.log("initial state is ", store.getState())
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => console.log("updated", store.getState()))
store.dispatch(buyCake())
store.dispatch(buyCake())
store.dispatch(buyCake())
store.dispatch(buyCake())
unsubscribe()
```

when i dispatch(buyCake()) then only it shows error but if i do store.dispatch({type:BUY_CAKE}) then code runs  fine why is the error occuring

Answer (score 0):

Because your return statement is wrongly formatted. Be aware of this deadly feature:

> JavaScript will automatically insert semicolons. Without the parentheses, JavaScript would ignore the following lines and return without a value.

This is your function with semicolons, which will return `undefined`:

```
function buyCake(){
return;
{
type:BUY_CAKE
};
};
```

Solution: Move your curly brackets to the `return` line:

```
function buyCake(){
  return {
      type: BUY_CAKE
    }
}
```

Comment: @ghostbbbm-MSP thnx